# Using pointers , memory gets overwritten , how to "reserve" memory?

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a class that **simulates an array** and makes use of **pointers**. Everything works well until my pointer values are **overwritten**.

Here's a sample of my code , this is the indexer that I use to get / set the values. As I said everything works well until at some point the address is overwritten with some other random values.

How can I **fix or "reserve" the space** for the length of the "array"?

```
public int this[int x]
    {
        get
        {
            if(x >= _length || x < 0)
            {
                throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
            }
            int* offsetToReturn = indexZeroPointer + x;

            return *offsetToReturn;
        }
        set
        {
            if (x >= _length || x < 0)
            {
                throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
            }

            int* offset = indexZeroPointer + x;

            *offset = value;
        }
    }
```

I used as index 0 for the array the address of a random integer I declared in class.

```
indexZeroPointer = &someValue;
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: For fun and why not? Just for education.

Comment: If you want to mess with pointers I recommend doing it in C++ instead of C#.

Comment: Where do you *allocate* the memory? How do you fill in the `indexZeroPointer`? Ideally, put in a short but complete working sample that shows the problem you're seeing.

Comment: Is any of this even done in an unsafe context?  It doesn't appear to be.

Comment: @Luaan well I created a random int and got that address. I am using that as index 0;

Comment: (you want to add that to your question, rather than posting it as a comment)

Comment: @DavidL yes the class is unsafe

Comment: Strange as it may seem, imo this question is __valid and not off topic__ by any stretch of the rules!

Comment: @TaW the question COULD be valid, if it included a small, reproducible example.

Comment: @TaW it is off-topic due to lack of [MCVE] - would be on-topic otherwise (easy to recover for OP)... Also with " I created a random int and got that address" it is very strange to expect any sensible behavior from the code.

Comment: The code is pretty close to what I would expect from a _small, reproducible example_. But I totally agree with _it is very strange to expect any sensible behavior from the code._  Which is the OP question _how to fix?_ Or: How to make a working _array simulation with hand-crafted pointers_. OK, 'crafted' is a euphemism ;-)

Comment: No, don't add the *answer* to your question. Just add how you got the `indexZeroPointer` in your original code, because that's needed for the MCV Alexei mentioned. Without that, your question really is off-topic :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't just randomly take addresses of objects in C#. You're in a managed memory environment where the locations in virtual memory space can (and will) change.

By taking the address of a single integer, you're *at best* getting four bytes of memory to use. You can't just access the memory *behind* the allocated piece and hope for the best - not only does it change (due to memory relocation), it will also be taken up by others. This is especially true if you got the address from a local, which would be allocated on the stack - you're rewriting the stack willy-nilly.

If you want to use pointers (relatively) safely, you need to ensure that the memory you use is actually *allocated*, and persisted as long as necessary. For example, if you know the length in advance, you can use this piece of code to get the "zero address":

```
var _length = 10;

var indexZeroPointer = (int*)Marshal.AllocHGlobal(_length * sizeof(int)).ToPointer();
```

This is just the very beginning of your problems, though. As soon as you enter pointer territory, you lose all the benefits of dealing with managed memory. You'll need to release memory as necessary, get rid of invalid or dangling pointers, handle all the bounds checking and many others.

This is yet another subject where just feeling your way around is going to hurt you. You really want to *learn* what you're doing, and how the architecture of the computer and the operating system works, and how all this integrates with the .NET memory model. As you just discovered, unsafe code has a tendency of appearing to work, while causing random issues all over the place if you don't know what you're doing (and even if you do - remember the Heartbleed bug and friends?). Make sure you *understand* how the lower layers work - by using unsafe code, the abstractions that help you avoid understanding that disappear. Low-level coding isn't very friendly.

Comment: This is what I wanted to hear. I will give that a try. Yes It makes total sense what you said.

Comment: That works perfect, thank you. I feel more educated. And yes I know I am not experienced enough to play with this stuff , but it is interesting.